# How to Read HTTPS pages dot net

Tags: c#, .net, https

I'm trying to make application to read context different websites
With `port 80` I do not have any problem but in many pages but  with   HTTPS ( `port 443` ?) I'm getting `error  403`

On the same box, I can open  the same pages  in IE and CHROME

What  can be done in C# to make that  read possible?

Comment: Are you trying to request from a different domain? Usually isn’t allowed in https

Comment: This is a console application that is trying to read the https webpage

Comment: Could you provide failed url? Do you try to get data from urls where authentication is required? And add your code.